# Including config files for lambdas

Tags: python, aws-lambda

I have created a lambda and I would like to access some files from a different directory (ie. `data_dir`).

How do I include them?

So far, I tried using layers and efs mount but I didn't manage to get either of these to work...

Here is my file system structure:

```
src
|__lambdas
      |__my_lambdas.py
data_dir
|__transform.xsl
|__schema.json
|__config.ini
```

I am currently using this template to `sam build --use-container` and `sam local invoke IngestFunction`

```
AWSTemplateFormatVersion: '2010-09-09'
Transform: AWS::Serverless-2016-10-31
Description: Description

Resources:
  IngestFunction:
    Type: AWS::Serverless::Function
    Properties:
      CodeUri: src/lambdas/
      Handler: my_lambdas.some_handler_method
      Runtime: python3.7
      Events:
        IngestSQS:
          Type: SQS
          Properties:
            Queue: arn:aws:sqs:eu-west-1:xxx:xxx
            BatchSize: 10
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

General your `CodeUri` has to point to location where all your files are available. It could be folder or archive.

First option is to zip it.

During your build package lambda.

```sh
zip -qr build/package.zip src data_dir
```

```yaml
Handler: src/lambdas/my_lambdas.some_handler_method
CodeUri: ./build/package.zip
```

Second option is copy files.

During your build copy files.

```sh
cp -r src build
cp -r data_dir build
```

```yaml
Handler: src/lambdas/my_lambdas.some_handler_method
CodeUri: ./build
```

Answer (score 1):

There is two approach you can do this for :

1. Keep this `data_dir` inside lambda folder itself and access within itself.
2. Create S3 Bucket `data_dir` and access this by `boto3` S3 `download_file` function each file.

For layer you have to create python package using `__init__.py` and load this dependant file and access using layer. You can't directly access.

Not sure about EBS mount haven't tried this option.